# How to configure the file path or url path in the Java Web, sometimes with a backslash sometimes do not need to add?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I see the web config is sometimes:

```
UPLOAD_FILE=D\:/upload/
FILE_URL=http\://127.0.0.1\:8080/FILE_CLIENT
```

Sometimes is   `UPLOAD_FILE=D:/upload/`, I tried in the windows, these two  work well in tomcat, I would like to ask what is the difference?
I think it is the reason of colon .It seems to be a escape character with a backslas. Why does it sometimes need to escape character ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows generally uses \ in their paths where UNIX systems use / in the path. Sometimes libraries and frameworks will replace "/" with "\" when running on Windows but not when running on other operating systems.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245156/is-it-safe-to-convert-windows-file-paths-to-unix-file-paths-with-a-simple-replac has a great discussion on this topic.

Comment: I think it is the reason of  colon .It seems to  be a escape character  with a backslas

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6 a colon does not need an escape character in Java